# Application wide mouse cursor overlay (Windows/WPF)

Tags: wpf

I have an application where the user is multiple mouse cursors variants to manipulate graphics. Some of the manipulations start longer running background processes, and the user is still able to proceed working on the data.

For eample, the user draws a circle. After the circle is drawn the coordinates are enqueued in background process queue that performs a complex operation that could take longer. The problem is that the user doesn't see this, so I wanted to show longer running operations as a small overlay (hourglass) in the currently active cursor.

Since the user can proceed working and the cursor changes according to the users selected operation I cannot simply set a different cursor.

So the question is if there is way to add an additional mouse cursor-overlay.

All the methods I have seen so far are continuously updating the cursor in some timer but this is causing flickering. The windows API also does not support overlays in a way that I can stack/layer cursors. Obviously it is necessary to merge them and then set it.

Is there any chance to get this easier?

Comment: Why should this state be visualized by the cursor, instead of (for example) in a status bar field, maybe even with a progress bar?

Comment: I have what sounds like quite a similar app shows a list of animated paths showing it's busy doing stuff. They're displayed in a horizontal itemscontrol just goes up in the top right of the window display area. As they spin they're fairly noticeable so you can see stuff's going on. But don't get in the way of the user.

Comment: @Clemens: Thats what I already have and the customers don't recognize,

Comment: @Andy. As said to Clemens, I already have many pie charts and progress bars flickering around. The problem is that they are not uniquely synchronized and slow down the application severely. Also the many progress inidicators are annoying the users. It seems that the most appropriate solution is to let a window "fly" with the mouse where I can so what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what I wanted, and maybe not completely finished, I came up with a solution using the `Wpf EventManager` which allows to register application-wide event handlers:

The solution is quite simple, you create a transparent window that moves with the mouse by intercepting the globally registered mouse event handlers. In the window you can do whatever you want. The MouseWindow in the example below just looks like this (it is just a transparent window with a circle in it):

```
<Window x:Class="WindowFollowMouse.MouseWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        ShowInTaskbar="False"
        Focusable="False"
        WindowStartupLocation="Manual"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        IsHitTestVisible="False"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        Background="Transparent"
        ShowActivated="False"
        Height="50" Width="50" Topmost="True" WindowStyle="None">
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse Width="50" Height="50" Stroke="Red"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Attached is a working piece of code that I still have to improve, but as a first shot it should help. The advantage is that compared to some suggested solution it doesn't need any low-level windows API hooks or windows API at all:

```
/// <summary>
/// Attaches an overlay to the mouse that is moved with the mouse cursor.
/// That way we can add more elaborate effects on the cursor.
/// </summary>
internal static class MouseOverlay
{
    public static readonly Lazy<MouseWindow> _mouseWindow = new(CreateMouseWindow);

    static MouseOverlay()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Install the tracker window and show it.
    /// </summary>
    public static void OverrideCursor()
    {
        // If the window is already created, we exit immediately.
        if (_mouseWindow.IsValueCreated)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Otherwise installed the handlers.
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Window), UIElement.MouseLeaveEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(LeaveHandler));
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Window), UIElement.MouseLeaveEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(EnterHandler));
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Window), UIElement.PreviewMouseMoveEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(MoveHandler));

        // and update the current position.
        UpdateMouseWindowPosition();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Show the tracker window if necessary.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private static void EnterHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        => UpdateMouseWindowPosition();

    /// <summary>
    /// Hide the tracker window if we leave the window.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private static void LeaveHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        => UpdateMouseWindowPosition();

    /// <summary>
    /// Update the tracker window on mouse moves.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    internal static void MoveHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        => UpdateMouseWindowPosition();

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to lazily create the mouse tracking window.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static MouseWindow CreateMouseWindow()
    {
        var mouseWindow = new MouseWindow()
        {
            Owner = null,
        };

        return mouseWindow;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Updates the tracking window according to the current position.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pt"></param>
    [SkipLocalsInit, MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveOptimization)]
    private static void UpdateMouseWindowPosition()
    {
        var window = _mouseWindow.Value;

        if (Mouse.DirectlyOver is FrameworkElement control)
        {
            var pt = Mouse.GetPosition(control);
            pt = control.PointToScreen(pt);

            window.Left = pt.X - window.Width / 2;
            window.Top = pt.Y - window.Height / 2;

            if (!window.IsVisible)
            {
                window.Show();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            window.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```